# how can I connect to an url adress using luasocket?

Tags: sockets, url, lua, connection, luasocket

This is my code:

```
socket = require('socket')
conn = socket.connect('http://chat.freenode.net', 6667)
if conn == true then
print('connected') else
print('error') end
```

I even tried to put http in the url but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error message (the second returned value), it should be fairly self-explanatory:

```
local socket = require('socket')
local conn, err = socket.connect('http://chat.freenode.net', 6667)
print(conn, err)
```

This prints `nil    "host or service not provided, or not known"`, because the URL you provided includes the scheme, which is not needed in this case. Try:

```
local conn, err = socket.connect('chat.freenode.net', 6667)
print(conn, err)
```

This should print something like `"tcp{client}: 05EBB998"`.